# Website editors with code editing available

Tags: html, editor, dreamweaver

Recently I've created a website in HTML for a friend  of mine. Part of his site is interactive and needs to be edited regularly. I created the website from scratch just with code, no editor. Seeing how the site needs to be updated frequently,is there a website editor where I can transfer my code to it and my friend can edit it in a nice GUI as he has no knowledge in HTMl. Sort of like dreamweaver but more user friendly as dreamweaver can be complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware Adobe were working on something, I'm not 100% sure whether they scrapped it or not, however I'm sure it would cost a fortune since Adobe tends to like money<3

After looking again, however, it seems that their only web platform is Dreamweaver, which I believe has received a number of updates so may be better than your memory serves, however, adobe Dreamweaver tends not to work well with websites that apply a fair amount of styling/script and renders them wrong in the preview section.

It might be worth looking at Adobe Muse? I'm not 100% sure what it actually is, however it suggests to be a site editor and offers a free trial?